# How to get the date Format directives of a date string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string in date format. It would be "2020-09-30", "09-30-2020", etc.
I would like to get back the Format directives of the date string.

For example, if the string is "2020-09-30", I would like to get back "%Y-%m-%d".

Comment: For a given date string, `s`, after converting it to a `Date` object, `d`, your only recourse is to construct an array of date formats `arr`, and then loop though `arr` looking for one, `fmt` such that `s == d.strftime(fmt) #=> true`. Even then, however,..

Comment: ...the date format found may not work for other dates in the same format. If, for example, the given date string were `s1 = '2020-11-22'`, so `d1 = Date.new(2020, 11, 22) #=> #<Date: 2020-11-22 ((2459176j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` we would find that `s1 ==  d1.strftime(fmt) #=> true` when `fmt #=> '%Y-%m-%d'`. If, however, `s2 =  '2020-9-2'` were another date in the same format, then with `d2 = Date.new(2020, 9, 2) #=> #<Date: 2020-09-02 ((2459095j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. `s = d2.strftime(fmt) #=> 
"2020-09-02"`, so `s2 == s #=> false`.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link by tweaking some the methods a bit you can get the desired result
https://railsexamples.com/ruby-date-formatting/

Comment: I have downvote because this does not answer the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for correcting we will try to give proper answer from next time